# Transpose horizontally stored data to multiple rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a sheet I need to transform from data being stored horizontally to vertically, i.e. from:

| Company ID | DoB | Name | DoB | Name | DoB | Name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ID 1 | DoB 1 | Name 1 | DoB 2 | Name 2 | DoB 3 | Name 3 |
| ID 2 | DoB 4 | Name 4 | DoB 5 | Name 5 |  |  |

To:

| Company ID | DoB | Name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ID 1 | DoB 1 | Name 1 |
| ID 1 | DoB 2 | Name 2 |
| ID 1 | DoB 3 | Name 3 |
| ID 2 | DoB 4 | Name 4 |
| ID 2 | DoB 5 | Name 5 |

The data is structured such that the DoB/name entities always occur periodically on rows as illustrated above. The number of entities stored horizontally on each row can vary from none to 16.

How would one go about solving this in Python/Pandas (or something else)? This is a one-time thing, so performance is not really an issue.

Thankful for any help!

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transpose.html?highlight=transpose#pandas.DataFrame.transpose

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
out = (df
   .set_index('Company ID')
   .pipe(lambda d: d.set_axis(
          pd.MultiIndex
            .from_arrays([d.columns,
                          d.groupby(level=0, axis=1).cumcount().add(1)]),
                              axis=1)
        )
   .stack()
   .reset_index().drop(columns='level_1')
   
)
```

Alternative:

```
out = pd.concat([g.stack().droplevel(1).rename(k)
                 for k,g in df.set_index('Company ID').groupby(level=0, axis=1)],
                 axis=1).reset_index()
```

output:

```
  Company ID    DoB    Name
0       ID 1  DoB 1  Name 1
1       ID 1  DoB 2  Name 2
2       ID 1  DoB 3  Name 3
3       ID 2  DoB 4  Name 4
4       ID 2  DoB 5  Name 5
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use `stack` in a for loop here:

```
res = pd.DataFrame()
for col in df.columns.drop('Company ID').unique():
    new_df = ( df.set_index('Company ID')[col].stack().reset_index().
                  rename({0:col}, axis=1)[['Company ID', col]] )
    res = pd.concat([res, new_df], axis=1)
# drop duplicated columns coming from stack    
res = res.loc[:, ~res.columns.duplicated()]
```

Output:

```
Company ID  DoB Name
0   ID 1    DoB 1   Name 1
1   ID 1    DoB 2   Name 2
2   ID 1    DoB 3   Name 3
3   ID 2    DoB 4   Name 4
4   ID 2    DoB 5   Name 5
```

Answer (score 1):

One option is with [pivot_longer](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/api/functions/#janitor.functions.pivot.pivot_longer) from [pyjanitor](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/):

```py
# pip install pyjanitor
import pandas as pd
import janitor
(df
.pivot_longer(
    index = 'Company ID', 
    names_to = '.value', 
    names_pattern= '(.+)', 
    sort_by_appearance=True)
.dropna()
) 
  Company ID    DoB    Name
0       ID 1  DoB 1  Name 1
1       ID 1  DoB 2  Name 2
2       ID 1  DoB 3  Name 3
3       ID 2  DoB 4  Name 4
4       ID 2  DoB 5  Name 5
```